# ggplot faceted cumulative histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data

```
set.seed(123)
x = c(rnorm(100, 4, 1), rnorm(100, 6, 1))
gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), each=100)
mydata = data.frame(x=x, gender=gender)
```

and I want to plot two cumulative histograms (one for males and the other for females) with ggplot. 
I have tried the code below

```
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=x, fill=gender)) + stat_bin(aes(y=cumsum(..count..)), geom="bar", breaks=1:10, colour=I("white")) + facet_grid(gender~.)
```

but I get this chart

[image]

that, obviously, is not correct.

How can I get the correct one, like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would pre-compute the `cumsum` values per bin per group, and then use `geom_histogram` to plot.

```
mydata %>%
    mutate(x = cut(x, breaks = 1:10, labels = F)) %>%      # Bin x
    count(gender, x) %>%                                   # Counts per bin per gender
    mutate(x = factor(x, levels = 1:10)) %>%               # x as factor
    complete(x, gender, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%            # Fill missing bins with 0
    group_by(gender) %>%                                   # Group by gender ...
    mutate(y = cumsum(n)) %>%                              # ... and calculate cumsum
    ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = gender)) +                     # The rest is (gg)plotting
    geom_histogram(stat = "identity", colour = "white") + 
    facet_grid(gender ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: Maurits, thanks for answering so quickly, but your bars do not fit exactly the intervals. In addition, I'm looking for a simpler way, if possible, avoiding the explicit computation of cumulative frequencies.

Comment: *"Maurits, thanks for answering so quickly, but your bars do not fit exactly the intervals."* What do you mean? Numbers are centred at the bars, which is how it should be for a histogram. In your case, numbers are *between* the bars, which is not correct.

Comment: In this case, the x variable is continuous, and for that reason I plot a histogram. In a histogram the width of the bar must be the width of the interval. The base of the first bar, for instance, must be the interval from 1 to 2 and should not be centered at 2. Anyway,  I'm not too worried about that. What is more important to me is if there is a simpler way to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: *"In a histogram the width of the bar must be the width of the interval"* @AlfredoSánchez Where ever did you hear that? That’s incorrect and not at all consistent with the standard definition and interpretation of a histogram. Anyway. I’ve given you my two cents and a straightforward solution. Doing data manipulation within `ggplot` is bad practice and I would certainly not call that a simpler solution but that’s obviously your choice.

Comment: _Where ever did you hear that?_ In many books. Just have a look at these:
https://www.wikihow.com/Draw-a-Histogram
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhCq0Xcvg_E
Thanks again for your answer. If nobody offers me a simpler way I'll take yours.

Comment: @AlfredoSánchez Hmm, that's an odd definition (and reference). More traditionally (according to e.g. Pearson, Fisher etc.) in a histogram (Fisher calls it a "frequency plot") you bin a continuous variable into "bins" and plot counts per bin. The bin number is an ordinal variable (i.e. an ordered categorical variable), that corresponds to an interval of a continuous variable. For equal-sized intervals (as is the case here), the width is completely irrelevant. As axis labels you can either show the bin number (like I do), or the left and right boundaries of the interval. Both are acceptable.

Comment: [...] In terms of my solution, it's easy to show the interval boundaries instead of bin numbers. But again, a *tidy* data visualisation approach keeps data manipulation and plotting separate: Meaning you should perform any data manipulation (like calculating the `cumsum` per group per bin) *prior* to plotting, and then simply pass the data to the plotting methods.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Edo, I also came here looking for exactly this.  @Edo's solution was the key for me.  It's great.  But I post here a few additions that increase the information density and allow comparisons across different situations.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
x = c(rnorm(100, 4, 1), rnorm(50, 6, 1))
gender = c(rep("Male", 100), rep("Female", 50))
grade = rep(1:3, 50)
mydata = data.frame(x=x, gender=gender, grade = grade)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x, 
                   y = ave(after_stat(density), group, FUN = cumsum)*after_stat(width),
                   group = interaction(gender, grade),
                   color = gender)) +
    geom_line(stat = "bin") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
    facet_wrap(~grade)
```

I rescale the `y` so that the cumulative plot always ends at 100%.  Otherwise, if the groups are not the same size (like they are in the original example data) then the cumulative plots have different final heights.  This obscures their relative distribution.

Secondly, I use `geom_line(stat="bin")` instead of `geom_histogram()` so that I can put more than one line on a panel.  This way I can compare them easily.

Finally, because I also want to compare across facets, I need to make sure the `ggplot` group variable uses more than just `color=gender`.  We set it manually with `group = interaction(gender, grade)`.
[image: plot_output_of_code]

Answer (score -1):

Answering a million years later....

I was looking for a solution for the same problem and I got here..

Eventually I figured it out by myself, so I'll drop it here in case other people will ever need it.

As required: no pre-work is necessary!

```
ggplot(mydata) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x = x, y = ave(..count.., group, FUN = cumsum), 
                       fill = gender, group = gender),
                       colour = "gray70", breaks = 1:10) +
    facet_grid(rows = "gender")
```

[image]